# Word how to add symbol in same line as text? (VB.NET - WORD)

Tags: vb.net, text, ms-word, symbols

I need to have a symbol followed by text all created by vb.net in word.
Like:
    [symbol] Yes, i accept!

note: ⬜ Yes i accept (its not what i pretend)
      [crossedbox] yes i accept (is what i want to make)

thx in advance

Here is my code

```
oPara(10) = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        oPara(10).Range.InsertSymbol(CharacterNumber:=53, Font:="Wingdings 2", Unicode:=True)
        oPara(10).Range.Text = "S"
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Size = 7
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Bold = True
        oPara(10).Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle

        oPara(10).Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        oPara(10).Range.Text = "Bla bla."
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Size = 7
        oPara(10).Range.Font.Bold = True
        oPara(10).Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle
        oPara(10).Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. Are you looking for CharacterNumber:=84

Comment: im sorry if i wasn't explicit. i want to add a symbol to a paragraph without affecting the rest of the paragraph (the letter S indicates the symbol (which is a marked box), the "character number:=" does nothing (and i dnt know why))

Comment: I'm sorry, my brain must not be functioning well today.. How do you mean "without affecting the rest of the paragraph"? The code you show us is going to end up with "Bla bla.", no matter what you do at the beginning because Range.Text will replace the entire Range. The 84, substituted in your line with `InsertSymbol` for 53, should display a checked box (instead of an empty one). Maybe if you show us what your code is producing, and how it differs from what you want that would help.

Comment: thx all.... :D problem solved bellow

Comment: I removed the Visual Studio tag as it is not appropriate.  According to the tag's description:  _"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your styling changes to affect the rest of the paragraph, then you can't use the Paragraph.Range to set styling. You will have to take more control over where the range is referencing by explicitly keeping a range reference and moving it within the paragraph. This way, the styling instructions apply only to the range, and not the entire paragraph. In your current example, you appear to be overwriting your symbol by setting the range text to "S", which is why InsertSymbol doesn't appear to be doing anything. Here's a snippet that should get you going:

```
Dim oWord As New Word.Application
oWord.Visible = True
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
Dim oRng As Word.Range = oPara.Range
oRng.InsertSymbol(CharacterNumber:=53, Font:="Wingdings 2", Unicode:=True)
oRng.Start = oRng.End + 1
oRng.Text &= " Yes I Accept"
oRng.Font.Name = "Calibri"
```

Inserts the following into a new word document:

[image]

So now that you've seen how ranges can be controlled a bit more, now you have to think about whether you really need to do that at all...because you could just save yourself that whole headache by simply using:

```
oPara.Range.Text = "⬜ Yes I Accept"
```

Comment: thx, yes, it appears that im going to stick to "⬜ Yes I Accept" from charmap, thanks everyone :D